# Stable Distribution of Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, almost-everywhere

If X and Y are identical independent Random Variables.
I have shown that X+Y and X have same distribution also i used the definition of stable distribution but i am enable to prove X=0 almost surely?
Can someone give me hint how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What is the variance of the sum, $\mathsf {Var}(X+Y)$, equal to when $X,Y$ are independent and identically distributed?   What is it equal to when $X+Y$ is identically distributed to $X$?   How is it possible to be equal to both?   If that is the case, what distribution must $X+Y$ have?   (Which is also the distribution of $X$ if they are identically distributed.)

Comment: Var(X+Y)=Var X+Var Y as they are independent.I am enable to think how X=0 almost surely from given we can obtain?

Comment: @BhushanJamsandekar Yes.  Now what is $\mathsf{Var}(X+Y)$ if $X+Y$ has the same distribution as $X$?

Comment: Var(X+Y) will be 0 if X+Y has same distribution as X. Is it imply Var(X+Y)=Var(X)=0? So X is degenerate random variable which takes value E(X) with probability 1?

Comment: Yes.  You have $Var(X+Y)=2Var(X)$ and $Var(X+Y)=Var(X)$, so therefore $Var(X)=0$.  If there is no variance from the mean, the value is almost certainly the mean. @BhushanJamsandekar

Comment: Thanks @ Graham Kemp. I get Var(X)=0 then How we conclude X=0 almost surely? Var(X)=0 which means X can take only one value E(X) which is constant and Var(Constant)=0.I am enable to get clear picture how to go? please help me. I know we have to get one set A where Prob(A)=0 and X=0 on A^c.

Comment: @BhushanJamsandekar $\mathsf {Var}(X)=\mathsf E\big({(X-\mathsf E(X))}^2\big)$ .  If we assume $X$ can realise any values other than $\mathsf E(X)$ with a measureable probability, then the variance cannot be zero. However, it is zero so, that assumption cannot be true.  Therefore $X$ is almost certainly $\mathsf E(X)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48153/discussion-between-bhushan-jamsandekar-and-graham-kemp).